# Prove that if $\sum_{t=1} ^{\infty} x_t = \infty$ where $x_t \in [0,1], \forall t$, then $\prod_{t = 1}^{\infty} (1-x_{t}) = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that if $\sum_{t=1} ^{\infty} x_t = \infty$ where $x_t \in [0,1], \forall t$, then $\prod_{t = 1}^{\infty} (1-x_{t}) = 0$.

Many thanks.

P/S:

- Not homework but it is a part of the proof in a research paper I am reading.
- It could be trivial but I may have missed something and could not figure it out yet.
- I checked that this result is true for $p$-series.
- My initial idea is that let $a_t := \prod_{\tau=1}^t (1-x_{\tau}), \forall t$ and then try to prove that the series $\sum_{t}a_t$ converges but I have not been able to prove it yet.

Comment: What does the notation $x_t$ stand for? Is it just an indexing scheme, or do we know something on the dependence of $x$ on $t$?

Comment: $(x_t)$ is a sequence indexed by $t \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Just use that $0\leq 1-x_t<e^{-x_t}$, and multiply these inequalities. At any rate, this is not a research level question, it would be more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GHfromMO: Yes, I agree that math.stackexchange seems like a better fit for this question. Please consider closing it. Thanks for the notice and clarification.

Comment: Some posts on [math.se] where this is shown: [Infinite product problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209108), [Suppose $1>a_n>0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n)=0$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1650202), [How to prove $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519656), etc.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Didn't know this question had been asked on math.stackexchange because I forgot the name "infinite product" to search for. I have found a solution but thanks anyway for the pointers.

Comment: @thanhtang Well, for math expressions searching is not easy, but if it helps, here is some advice specific to [math.se]: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)
In this case I'd guess that quick ways could be [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cprod_%7Bt%20%3D%201%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20(1-x_%7Bt%7D)%20%3D%200%24&p=1) or  checking the [frequent tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-product?tab=Frequent) of the tag (infinite-product).

Answer (score 1):

The proof can be found [in this reference](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Infinite_product).

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch proof** (relating the infinite product to the infinite sum via the inequality $e^x \geq 1 + x, \forall x$):

Since $x_t \leq -\log(1 - x_t), \forall t$ and $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} x_t = \infty$, we have $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} (-1)\log(1- x_t) = \infty$. Thus, $\prod_{t=1}^{\infty} (1-x_t)$ must either does not exist or equals $0$ (if exists). Since $a_t := \prod_{\tau=1}^{t} (1-x_{\tau}), \forall t$ is a non-increasing sequence and bounded below (by $0$), thus $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} a_t$ exists which is then $0$.